# WP8 - Code to find connected Accounts

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can I programmatically find out what accounts a phone user has connected to his Windows Phone?

For example, I have connected my Gmail, Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn accounts to my phone and I get all the contacts in the People Hub. Is there anyway I can use C# to get me a list of these connected accounts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in current SDK.